# Boundary of Convergence of $\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{z^{2^n}}{\log(n)}$

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, measure-theory, convergence-divergence, fourier-analysis

So yesterday I posted a question about the behavior of $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{z^{2^n}}{n}$ on the unit circle and it was brought to my attention that for any $\epsilon>0,$ the sum
$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{z^{2^n}}{n^\epsilon}$ converges almost everywhere on the unit circle, despite there existing a dense subset of the unit circle where the sum is diverging to positive real infinity. So now I'm wondering if the same is true of
$\sum_{n=2}^\infty\frac{z^{2^n}}{\log(n)}?$ Or, perhaps a more enriching question is, for the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{z^{2^n}}{\phi(n)}$ where $\phi:\mathbb{N}\rightarrow(0,\infty)$ is monotonically increasing to infinity, how slow must $\phi(n)$ grow for this to stop being true?

Comment: Theorem 5.1 in [here](https://andrescaicedo.files.wordpress.com/2014/11/korner-behaviourofpowerseries.pdf) shows that at some points the partial sums must remain bounded.

Comment: @NDB Yes, I see that, you always show me the most powerful theorems haha.

Comment: For lacunary trigonometric series $\sum a_k e^{i n_k t}, n_{k+1}/n_k \ge q>1$ the necessary and sufficient condition of convergence on a positive measure set is $\sum |a_k|^2 < \infty$; the proof is in Zygmund Trigonometric series chapter 5

Comment: @Conrad Is that true? The necessary part of that statement seems to be contradictory to Carleson’s theorem. Unless I’m misunderstanding the statement.

Comment: Note that here we are talking about lacunary series not general trigonometric series; Carleson theorem applies to general trigonometric series, but lacunary series are very special so summability and convergence are same for them (usually convergence is stronger of course), convergence (or even summability as above) on a set of positive measure implies $L^2$, convergence to zero on a set of positive measure implies function zero etc; see chapter 5 in Zygmund bible on the subject

Comment: Actually the result about convergence on set positive measure implies $L^2$ for lacunary series is fairly intuitive since lacunarity implies that in the expansion of $|f|^2$ there aren't that many off diagonal terms so they essentially are dominated by the diagonal terms so when you integrate on a set of positive measure $|f|^2$ you get an inferior bound of the type $K(\sum |a_k|^2)$